# Getting error message after upgrading Node.js in Ubuntu!

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, nodejs

I was trying to upgrade Node.js from v6.5.0 to v6.9.1 by running the commands given below from terminal :-

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

After upgrading, when I check the version using `node -v`, it shows the error given below :-

```
bash /usr/bin/node no such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually create a symlink `/usr/bin/node`. Shortcut for bash compatible shells:

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

Or if you use non-standard shells, just hardcode the path you find with which nodejs:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04